# how to allow only spaces and alpha in name fields php using regex

Tags: php, regex

hi guys below is my regex to allow only alphabets and spaces with single quote and hypen in the first and last name

```
 $no_digit = array('firstname'=>$_POST['firstname'],'lastname'=>$_POST['lastname'],'city'=>$_POST['city']
                               ,'country'=>$_POST['country'],'state'=>$_POST['state']);
            foreach($no_digit as $index => $text){

                echo '<br>regex = ' . preg_match("#[a-zA-Z - ']#",$text);
                    $error_flag = true;
                    $error[$index] = "Wrong Character Found";


            }
```

i dont know it is not doing what i want please can some one show how it should be done or what am i missing or doing absolutly wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(preg_match("~[^a-zA-Z\-']~",$text)){
    $error_flag = true;
    $error[$index] = "Wrong Character Found";
}
```

Comment: thanks it is not taking the hypen and single qoute i changed it to [~[^a-zA-Z - \']~] but no luck

Comment: now should works. We need to escape - because it not represents chars diapason