# Regex to allow only letters , a single space and "-"

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a function to validate name in my application.A valid name can contain letters in both upper-case and lower-case , may contain `-` as well.

```
<?php
function ValidateName($input) {
    if(!preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z- ]/",$input)) {
        return "The name is invalid";
    } else { return $input;}
}

$name = "Joe Dow";
echo ValidateName($name);
?>
```

It still output name is invalid.I think the regex must be wrong here.Also i would to convert any multiple spaces into a single space

Comment: your logic is backwards. "If the string DOESN'T contain (`!preg`) any characters that are NOT (`[^...]`) ... then return as invalid".

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925385/how-to-allow-only-spaces-and-alpha-in-name-fields-php-using-regex?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/",$input)
```

Guess you needed this.Try this validation instead of rejecting a match.If it matches this is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Change this: `/[^a-zA-Z- ]/` to this: `/[^a-zA-Z -]+/`.

The problem was most likely the `-` not being at the end.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Yes sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex needs to have **unescaped hyphen** either at start or end in character class:

```
/[^a-zA-Z -]/
```

Also you have conditions reversed, your code can be:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/', $input)) { 
   return "The name is invalid";  
} else {
   return $input;
}
```